# Original stylesheet settings ignored when inline styles are removed with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a stylesheet which has some styles set.

One of the styles has **position** set to 'fixed' - but only for certain combinations.

So, for instance:

```
.mystyle.blue {
    position: fixed;
}
```

So, `.blue` is fixed, but plain `.mystyle` doesn't receive the same styling by itself.

I also have some jQuery stuff, which adds and removes inline styles. So, under certain conditions, it might add `position: fixed` to all `.mystyle` variants.

This is simply done using:

`$(".mystyle").css("position", "fixed")` to add;

and `$(".mystyle").removeAttr("style");` to remove.

However, once removed, the underlying stylesheet settings are then ignored. So, where I still expect `.mystyle.blue` to honour `position: fixed`, it doesn't.

Any idea as to a workaround?

UPDATE

I now know whats happening, and have a fix, but it's not what I expected should happen.

When setting `position: fixed` using jQuery, I also set a **top position**. This is a negative - `-64px` (although in reality, it's set dynamically). Obviously, both are removed at the same time.

The stylesheet code is this:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
```

Which I thought would take effect again once the inline style styles were removed - one does, one doesn't.

The negative top position doesn't seem revert to 0. This could just be my poor understanding. The position does revert to default.

If I add an important tag to `top: 0!important`, it does work.

Comment: It should work, do you have a working example ?

Comment: A snippet will help detect the problem.!

Comment: You don't need a "workaround". Browsers and jQuery are stable enough for handling these basic stuff. The issue must be in your code.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/rchdmzku/5/

Comment: @undefined - I'm looking through the code now.

Comment: @JohnOhara That's great John! I'm sure you can find the problem yourself.

Comment: John, the behavior you describe in the question does not happen in the jsFiddle you provided above. Can you please make a fiddle that **does** show the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `.mystyle` variants. `.mystyle.blue` is a composite CSS selector applying rules to any element that has both `myStyle` and `blue` classes, while it has both of them. If you remove any of them, the rules no longer apply.

```
$(".mystyle").css("position", "fixed")
```

adds `position:fixed;` inside the `style` attribute of any element in the page that currently has the class of `mystyle`. Please note `mystyle` and `myStyle` are **different** classes. CSS selector are case sensitive!

Any inline style rules have higher specificity than classes applied via CSS rules, unless the stylesheet rules are suffixed with `!important` (which you shouldn't use, it's a can of worms!).

```
$(".mystyle").removeAttr("style");
```

will remove the `style` attribute entirely, not only your added `position:fixed;`. If you do this to elements that previously have `style` attributes you'll lose those rules after you hide and show the element again. It's better to revert the `position` property to the default value of `static`:

```
$('.mystyle').css({position:'static'})
```